# Simple cold to extends SwingWorker to help to count value in the background

Tags: java

This is a simple code that extends `SwingWorker` to help counting value in the background.
But when I run the code, it just skip to finished. For example, if I enter a number 5, it should display `5 4 3 2 1 finished!`.
I guess maybe my declaration has problems.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class LabResponsiveGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private final String TEXT_COUNT_DOWN = "Count down!";
    private final String TEXT_CANCEL = "Cancel!";

    private JTextField txt = new JTextField("3");
    private JButton button = new JButton(TEXT_COUNT_DOWN);
    //private JButton button1 = new JButton(TEXT_CANCEL);

    private JTextArea txtOutput = new JTextArea(10, 20);

    public LabResponsiveGUI() {
        super("Simple GUI example");
        setSize(400, 400);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        //button1.addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        add(txt, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(txtOutput);
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int value ;

        BackgroundTask bgt = new BackgroundTask();

        bgt.execute();

        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
            if (value <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a number greater than zero");
                return;
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a valid integer");
            return;
        }
    }


    public class BackgroundTask extends SwingWorker<Void,String> {
        private int value;

        public  void BackgroudTask(int value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            try {
                int count =  value;
                String line = null;
                while (count > 0) {
                    line = String.valueOf(count);
                    txtOutput.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    count--;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                txtOutput.append("Finished! ");
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LabResponsiveGUI frame = new LabResponsiveGUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code compiling as i dont see an empty constructor for BackGroundTask?

Comment: Improved code formatting

Comment: Knock yourself out with editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change method

```
public void BackgrodTask(int value) {
```

to

```
public BackgroundTask(int value) {
```

and call the new constructor after `value` has been determined